# FCKeditor disable using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'content' ) ;
    oFCKeditor.BasePath = "js/Javascript/fckeditor/" ;
    oFCKeditor.Height = 300;
    oFCKeditor.Width = 600;
    oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() ;
}
function fnenable(){
    var myValue=document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked;
    var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('content');
    if(myValue==true) { 
        oEditor.EditorDocument.body.disabled=false;
    } else {
        oEditor.EditorDocument.body.disabled=true;
    }
}
</script>
```

I have Followed the site http://www.fckeditor.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=69.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you execute fnenable()?

Comment: Why not to use the new version: CKEDITOR http://ckeditor.com/?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I would suggest TinyMCE:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Sorry, it's been too long since I've used FCKeditor. My gut tells me it's in how you're trying to get the "body" property.

Comment: how do i replace textarea with TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
editorInstance.EditorDocument.body.contentEditable='false'; 
editorInstance.EditorDocument.designMode='off';
```

I also recomend upgrade the editor to the new CKEDITOR (without the F): http://ckeditor.com/